# scipy's `ode` solver with 'vode' method gives an empty array result

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, ode

I am attempting to integrate the equation

```
bg' = dmat*bg + releasevec.
```

`Dmat` is a 6x6 array of values and `bg` is a 6x1 vector.  To multiply `dmat` and `bg`, I use the dot product.  Then the `releasevec` is added to this product.

I want to integrate this equation on the timespan from zero to three.  Right now, the code below is producing an `f_results` that is an empty array, i.e. no results.

A little background is that this code is adapted from a MATLAB ode solver (`ode15s` specifically).  The apparent Python equivalent for `ode15s` is scipy's

```
ode.set_integrator('vode', method = 'bdf')
```

From the timespan 0 to 1, the `bg` results produced in `f_results` should be

```
[5.76068434946487e-16, 1.92039036486442e-14, 2.97732034735096e-21,
 1.15568146353068e-18, 3.50848451366317e-19, 6.99348172634721e-27]
```

As you can see, these bg results are hardly different from initial `bg` (`bg0`) values supplied in the code.  I know MATLAB's `ode15s` solver uses internal timesteps to perform the integration, so I figure messing with step parameters in the integrator may be necessary.

**Question**: Why am I getting an empty array as my result?  Have I set up the initial conditions incorrectly? How can I produce that next set of `bg` values that I posted as well?

If I omitted any relevant information or anything, let me know and I'll fix it ASAP.

```
def ode_solv(t, bg, dmat, releasevec):
    ydot[0] = dmat2[0].dot(bg) + releasevec[0]
    ydot[1] = dmat2[1].dot(bg) + releasevec[1]
    ydot[2] = dmat2[2].dot(bg) + releasevec[2]
    ydot[3] = dmat2[3].dot(bg) + releasevec[3]
    ydot[4] = dmat2[4].dot(bg) + releasevec[4]
    ydot[5] = dmat2[5].dot(bg) + releasevec[5]
    return ydot

ydot = np.zeros(6)

dmat2 = np.array([[-1960368.83845003, 58694.00323479, 39129.33548986, 1862545.49972536, 0.0, 0.0],
              [58694.00323479, -1.89355617e+09, 0.0, 1231.23020241, 21038.6060172, 14025.7373448],
              [39129.33548986, 0.68216154, -7.57402415e+09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [1862545.49972536, 0.0, 0.0, -9.28416441e+08, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 21038.64595532, 0.0, 0.0, -1.15156310e+09, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 14025.76397021, 0.0, 0.0, -5.97115916e+09]], np.float)
bg0 = [5.74717437413422e-16, 1.91588665922461e-14, 2.97070077781448e-21,
   1.15297115567223e-18, 3.50025640453469e-19, 6.97793289948656e-27]

releasevec = [0.0, 0.0000363636, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

t0 = 0.0
t1 = 3

f_results = []

soln = ode(ode_solv).set_integrator('vode', method='bdf', order=5)
soln.set_initial_value(t0, bg0)
soln.set_f_params(dmat2, releasevec)
while soln.t < t1:
    soln.integrate(soln.bg)
    f_results.append([soln.t, soln.bg])
print f_results
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is not correct:

```
soln.set_initial_value(t0, bg0)
```

You have the arguments reversed.  The first argument must be the initial *value*; the second (optional) argument is the time at which that value is given.

There are a couple other problems:

- Change `soln.bg` to `soln.y`.
- The line `soln.integrate(soln.bg)` is not correct.  The argument should be the next desired `t` value.

Take a(nother) look at the example in [the `ode` docstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html).

Comment: Thanks @Warren Weckesser.  I took a look at the ode docstring and specifically the source documentation for 'vode.'  Upon reading about the method flag, I would like to set one.  Do you have any idea on how to do this in Python?  Method flag or MF is not one of the additional parameters for set_integrator

Comment: @deelsburyyy you're already setting `method='bdf'` in your code

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the things that Warren just pointed out, you could massively simplify and speed up your `ode_solv` function by vectorizing it:

```
def ode_solv(t, bg, dmat, releasevec):
    return dmat2.dot(bg) + releasevec
```

You also don't need to access the `soln.y` attribute directly - the result of the call to `integrate` is the new value of `bg` for that timestep, i.e.:

```
bg = soln.integrate(t)
results.append(bg)
```

Comment: Thanks @ali_m.  The vectorization was a good suggestion and it worked